# Azure table storage querying rowkey of specified length

Tags: azure, key, row, storage

I'm using Azure Storage Table and I've got entries like this :

```
PK      RK            TypeOfSerializedObject
foo_0   bar_0         type1
foo_0   bar_0_var_1   type2
```

Is there any solution to retrieve the first one row (bar_0) without the other (bar_0_var_1)?
(In my case these two rows store serialized object of different types and I can't retrieve both of it).

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
            IQueryable<type1> type1ent = from t in context.CreateQuery<type1>(tableName)
                                         where t.PartitionKey == String.Format("foo_{0:0}", arg1)
                                         && t.RowKey.CompareTo("bar_0") >= 0
                                         && t.RowKey.CompareTo("bar_9") <= 0
                                         select t;
```

And I need to include some query option like "t.RowKey.Length == 5", but it's invalid.

Have you got any ideas?

EDIT:

Finally I've decided to change the data structure to something like this :

```
PK      RK            TypeOfSerializedObject
foo_0   bar_0         type1
foo_0   var_1         type2
foo_0   var_2         type3
foo_0   var_3         type4
foo_0   var_4         type5
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it that (not efficient) way **but I'm still looking after solution with better performance** :

```
            IQueryable<string> type1ent = from t in context.CreateQuery<type1>(tableName)
                                                            where t.PartitionKey == String.Format("foo_{0:0}", arg1)
                                                            && t.RowKey.CompareTo("bar_0") > 0
                                                            && t.RowKey.CompareTo("bar_:") < 0
                                                            select new String(t.RowKey.ToArray());

             foreach(string rowKey in type1ent)
                if (rowKey.Length == "bar_0".Length)
                {
                    type1Entity = (from t in context.CreateQuery<type1>(tableName)
                                   where t.PartitionKey == String.Format("foo_{0:0}", arg1)
                                   && t.RowKey.CompareTo(rowKey) == 0
                                   select t).FirstOrDefault();

                    TYPE type = // deserialization of type1Entity.SerializedObject
                }
```

Comment: Your 1st query to fetch the data is perfectly fine. It's not clear to me why you're fetching the same data 2nd time.

Comment: I've got two types of data in the storage :

foo_0 bar_0       is of type "type1"
foo_0 bar_0_var_1 is of type "type2"

(I'll edit 1st post to clarify that).

Therefore, I can't retrieve both of that entries in 1st query.
So I decided to retrieve only rowKeys from the 1st query, check if it's length alright and if so, get this from the query again with certainty of correct type.